# Neo.TransientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailure

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j v2.2 64-bit Windows

Attempting to load via csv file using the browser interface. After several successful load operations using [LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:filename.csv" AS csvLine] I am running into the following error:  Neo.TransientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailure

Executing the same load statement without using the csv file creates the records in neo4j, but it simply would not work with the file.

Any suggestions as to what might be happening? I have run out of ideas.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: how does the file in question look like? Any weird stuff in there like "strange" chars, BOM, etc?

Comment: perhaps try to provide an absolute file-url-path to the file or an http url.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this syntax? 'file:c:/path/to/data.csv'